# Ag-grid-enterprise with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid-enterprise in my system.
I'm also using react as my main framework.

So far used react 15.4 version, with ag-grid-enterprise of version 8.
In order to make enterprise work with react, I used ag-grid-react package, and changed the require paths from 'ag-grid' to 'ag-grid-enterprise', it worked fine.

Now we're migrating our system to react 16, and therefore had to update ag-grid as well, to the latest (13).

In github release it says version 13 is adapted to react 16. Is there a way to use ag-grid-enterprise directly without using ag-grid-react and adapting it? 
(this arrangement for the new version throws an exception)

Also, unlike previous versions, ag-grid-enterprise requires installing ag-grid as well, does it make sense?

Hope for your help,
Thanks

Comment: If you're an Enterprise customer I'd recommend you post your on the ag-Grid forum here: https://ag-grid.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, posted in their forum and got an answer.
https://www.ag-grid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=6470

Comment: The forums are busted. The answer should have been a part of this post.